# Local table of contents (etoc) in part title (titlesec)

Tags: titlesec, etoc

I have a problem with combining `titlesec` and `etoc`, are they compatible?
I want to use formating from `titlesec` and then after part title, on the same page, I want to add local table of contents. However my result for now is an empty `Content`.
I have the following formating from `titlesec`:

```
 \titleformat{\part}[frame]
 {\normalfont\color{gray}}
 {\filright
 \enspace \large PART \thepart\enspace}
 {20pt}
 {\Huge\bfseries\filcenter\color{black}}
 [{\localtableofcontents*
 }]
```

It works when I put manualy `\localtableofcontents*` after `\part{...}` command. However then  `\localtableofcontents*` is on the next page, I want it on the same page just after part title. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Testing with this mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gray}{gray}{0.75}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoc}\etocsettocstyle{}{}
\titleformat{\part}[frame]
 {\normalfont\color{gray}}
 {\filright
 \enspace \large PART \thepart\enspace}
 {20pt}
 {\Huge\bfseries\filcenter\color{black}}
 [\localtableofcontents]
\begin{document}
%\errorcontextlines5
%\tracingmacros1
\part{first part}
\section{A}
\section{B}
\section{C}

\part{second part}
\section{U}
\section{V}
\section{W}

\end{document}
```

shows two problems:

1. `titlesec` complains about "nested titles", because `\localtableofcontents` will use some `\section*`. I added `\etocsettocstyle{}{}` to suppress that.
2. the more serious problem is that `titlesec`'s version of `\part` will do `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}...` *after* executing the "after-code" part, i.e. after `\localtableofcontents` gets executed. This means that `etoc` mechanism to delimit local table of contents is broken, because `etoc` can not know it is after a `\part`.

Thus, 2. looks definitive. You can't do this. Simply insert `\localtableofcontents` manually in the appropriate locations after having forcibly convinced `titlesec` by whatever means you find most convenient to not do a `\clearpage` (according to your question which did not say which document class you are using). There is no problem with `article` class as in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gray}{gray}{0.75}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoc}\etocsettocstyle{\color{gray}}{}
\titleformat{\part}[frame]
 {\normalfont\color{gray}}
 {\filright
 \enspace \large PART \thepart\enspace}
 {20pt}
 {\Huge\bfseries\filcenter\color{black}}
\begin{document}
\part{first part}
\localtableofcontents
\section{A}
\section{B}
\section{C}

\part{second part}
\localtableofcontents
\section{U}
\section{V}
\section{W}

\end{document}
```

[image]